# Reading XML file from PL/SQL developer

Tags: xml, oracle, stored-procedures, plsql

Below is the procedure which i have taken from net..but while executing its giving me error that "xmlgen.setRowsetTag must be declared"

Please tell me if this error is due to some setting mistakes or i have to include some files..
I am using PL/SQL developer 10g

Thankss:-

```
create or replace procedure SP_XML_TEST is
begin
declare 
xmlString CLOB := null; 
-- Here we are reading 250 bytes at a time. We should be really reading a 
-- whole chunk. dbms_output.put_line can only accomodate 256 characters per line 
-- so we have this limitation. 
amount integer:= 255; 
position integer := 1; 
charString varchar2(255); 

begin 

xmlgen.setRowTag('EMP_ROW');                     -- we want the row element to be    named    EMP_ROW. 

 xmlgen.setRowsetTag('EMP_RESULTS');        -- we want the result document root to be EMP_RESULTS. 
 xmlgen.setMaxRows(3);                                       -- limit the output to 3 rows. 
 xmlgen.setskipRows(2);                                       -- skip the first two rows in the query before outputing results. 
 xmlgen.useLowerCaseTagNames();                   -- set the tag names to be all in lower case. 
 xmlgen.setErrorTag('ERROR_RESULT');           -- set the ERROR tag to be  ERROR_RESULTS. 
 xmlgen.setRowIdAttrName('ENO');                    -- set the id attribute in the ROW element to be ENO. 
 xmlgen.setRowIdColumn('EMPNO');                 -- use the EMPNO column's value for the id attribute. 
 xmlgen.useNullAttributeIndicator(false);          -- do not use the null indicator to indicate nullness. 
 xmlgen.setStyleSheet('http://www.oracle.com/xsl');  -- attach the stylesheet PI to the result document. 

 xmlString := xmlgen.getXML('select * from scott.emp ',1); -- This gets the XML out 

 dbms_lob.open(xmlString,DBMS_LOB.LOB_READONLY);  -- Now open the lob data.. 
 loop 
 dbms_lob.read(xmlString,amount,position,charString);      -- read the lob data 
 dbms_output.put_line(charString); 
 position := position + amount; 
 end loop; 

 exception 
 when no_data_found then 
dbms_lob.close(xmlString);                                                   -- end of    fetch, free the lob 
dbms_lob.freetemporary(xmlString); 
xmlgen.resetOptions; 
when others then 
 xmlgen.resetOptions; 
  end; 


   end SP_XML_TEST;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem with picking stuff up from Das Interweb is that quality control can be very poor.  In particular you need to pay attention to *version numbers*.  You're on Oracle 10g.  I think XMLGEN was introduced in the XDK for Oracle 8i; it was deprecated in favour of the PL/SQL package [DBMS_XMLGEN](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14258/d_xmlgen.htm#i1012053) in 9i, and (as far as I know) hasn't been included in the database for some years.

DBMS_XMLGEN does similar sorts of things to XMLGEN, although some of the procedures have  slightly different signatures and some have been dropped altogether.  I have rewritten the posted code to use DBMS_XMLGEN.

```
create or replace procedure SP_XML_TEST is
    xmlString CLOB;
    amount integer:= 255;
    position integer := 1;
    charString varchar2(255);
    len pls_integer;

    l_ctx  dbms_xmlgen.ctxHandle;

begin

    l_ctx := dbms_xmlgen.newcontext('select * from apc.emp');

    dbms_xmlgen.setRowTag(l_ctx, 'EMP_ROW');                     -- we want the row element to be    named    EMP_ROW.
    dbms_xmlgen.setRowsetTag(l_ctx, 'EMP_RESULTS');        -- we want the result document root to be EMP_RESULTS.
    dbms_xmlgen.setMaxRows(l_ctx, 3);                                       -- limit the output to 3 rows.
    dbms_xmlgen.setskipRows(l_ctx, 2);                                       -- skip the first two rows in the query before outputing results.

    xmlString := dbms_xmlgen.getXML(l_ctx  ); -- This gets the XML out

    dbms_output.put_line('rows read = '||to_char(dbms_xmlgen.GETNUMROWSPROCESSED(l_ctx)));
    len := dbms_lob.getlength  (xmlString);

    dbms_lob.open(xmlString,DBMS_LOB.LOB_READONLY);  -- Now open the lob data..
    loop
        dbms_lob.read(xmlString,amount,position,charString);      -- read the lob data
        dbms_output.put_line(charString);
        position := position + amount;
        EXIT when position > len;
    end loop;

    dbms_lob.close(xmlString);
    dbms_xmlgen.closecontext(l_ctx);

end SP_XML_TEST;
/
```

And lo!

```
SQL> exec SP_XML_TEST
rows read = 3
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<EMP_RESULTS>
 <EMP_ROW>
  <EMPNO>8085</EMPNO>

<ENAME>TRICHLER</ENAME>
  <JOB>PLUMBER</JOB>
  <MGR>8061</MGR>

<HIREDATE>08-APR-10</HIREDATE>
  <SAL>3500</SAL>
  <DEPTNO>50</DEPTNO>

</EMP_ROW>
 <EMP_ROW>
  <EMPNO>7369</EMPNO>
  <
ENAME>CLARKE</ENAME>
  <JOB>CLERK</JOB>
  <MGR>7902</MGR>

<HIREDATE>17-DEC-80</HIREDATE>
  <SAL>800</SAL>
  <DEPTNO>20</DEPTNO>

</EMP_ROW>
 <EMP_ROW>
  <EMPNO>7499</EMPNO>
  <ENAME>VAN WIJK</ENAME>

<JOB>SALESMAN</JOB>
  <MGR>7698</MGR>
  <HIREDATE>20
-FEB-81</HIREDATE>
  <SAL>1600</SAL>
  <COMM>300</COMM>
  <DEPTNO>30</DEPTNO>

</EMP_ROW>
</EMP_RESULTS>
```

---

Incidentally, something else which has changed since the original coder hacked that procedure is the limitation on the DBMS_OUTPUT buffer.  In 10g it can go up to 32767.  [Find out more](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14258/d_output.htm#i1000105).